# What are alternatives to Postini for spam filtering?

Tags: email, spam-prevention, postini

I'm looking for a good spam filtering service for a small business (< 25 people).  I'm looking for a solution similar to Postini, where I set my MX records to route mail for my domain to the spam service, they do the filtering and then send the mail to the destination.

Postini is certainly inexpensive enough our technical folks believe the configuration options and user interface are complex.

What alternatives exist that might be more simple?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Leo Laporte gushes about [MailRoute](http://mailroute.info/).

Comment: @Al Everett-Thanks their product looks good.Unrelated I think Leo is a disaster,he only has basic technical skills,he says TWiT is aimed at "tech people" but in reality it's not,he never knows enough to drill into a topic, and on the rest of the shows he dominates the conversation, talking over the host who has more knowledge.Leo is about building his network in any way possible not about delivering quality content.His audience is so big because he goes for least common denominator.His goal is building an audience in any way possible and crappy content is the quickest way.Besides that I lovem!